# Test of 3000 messages are received or not. Need 3000 US numbers & check if messages are received on them

Tags: testing

I want to test that 3000 users received the text messages I sent them from my product to them. 
We are using Twilio multiple numbers (10) to speed up the delivery.
Now I want to test that when each user receives the text and if all 3000 users received it or not.

Basically, I am looking for a solution for fake numbers (at least 3000). So I can send the message to those test numbers and check the received messages as well.

Comment: Well, I have been using fake numbers to receive the text but I have found the limited count of them on the internet i.e. 50 numbers only so far